# MongoDB aggregate for localize

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'am new on mongoDB, I am trying to implement localization for something catalogs, asume I have two collections like this:

```
db={
  tipo_traslados: [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f74c774bd714d0e90b2612d"
      },
      "tipo": "one-way",
      "activo": true,
      "traslado": "apto-hotel",
      "descripcion": "apto-hotel-desc",
      "clave": "apto-hotel",
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f74c865bd714d0e90b2612e"
      },
      "tipo": "one-way",
      "activo": true,
      "traslado": "hotel-apto",
      "descripcion": "hotel-apto-desc",
      "clave": "hotel-apto",
    }
  ],
  locales: [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fe13c9253b7e8082ce7d5bc"
      },
      "etiqueta": "one-way",
      "locales": [
        {
          "clave": "ES",
          "valor": "Sencillo"
        },
        {
          "clave": "US",
          "valor": "One Way"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fe13d1c53b7e8082ce7d5bd"
      },
      "etiqueta": "apto-hotel",
      "locales": [
        {
          "clave": "ES",
          "valor": "Aeropuerto-Hotel"
        },
        {
          "clave": "US",
          "valor": "Airport-Hotel"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fe13dbb53b7e8082ce7d5be"
      },
      "etiqueta": "apto-hotel-desc",
      "locales": [
        {
          "clave": "ES",
          "valor": "Traslado Sencillo del Aeropuerto al Hotel"
        },
        {
          "clave": "US",
          "valor": "One Way Transfer from the Airport to the Hotel"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fe13dbb53b7e8082ce7d5be"
      },
      "etiqueta": "hotel-apto-desc",
      "locales": [
        {
          "clave": "ES",
          "valor": "Traslado Sencillo del Hotel al Aeropuerto"
        },
        {
          "clave": "US",
          "valor": "One Way Transfer from the Hotel to the Airport"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

i am try with aggregate to obtain the translations depending from value of ***clave*** (EN or ES):

```
db.tipo_traslados.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "locales",
      "localField": "tipo",
      "foreignField": "etiqueta",
      "as": "translate_tipo"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "locales",
      "localField": "descripcion",
      "foreignField": "etiqueta",
      "as": "translate_desc"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      tipo: 1,
      descripcion: 1,
      translate_tipo: "$translate_tipo.locales.valor",
      translate_desc: "$translate_desc.locales.valor"
    }
  }
])
```

I obtained a result very close that I need, it's some like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f74c774bd714d0e90b2612d"),
    "descripcion": "apto-hotel-desc",
    "tipo": "one-way",
    "translate_desc": [
      [
        "Traslado Sencillo del Aeropuerto al Hotel",
        "One Way Transfer from the Airport to the Hotel"
      ]
    ],
    "translate_tipo": [
      [
        "Sencillo",
        "One Way"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f74c865bd714d0e90b2612e"),
    "descripcion": "hotel-apto-desc",
    "tipo": "one-way",
    "translate_desc": [
      [
        "Traslado Sencillo del Hotel al Aeropuerto",
        "One Way Transfer from the Hotel to the Airport"
      ]
    ],
    "translate_tipo": [
      [
        "Sencillo",
        "One Way"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

But what I really need if I choose "EN" is something like that:

```
{
    ...
    "translate_desc": "One Way Transfer from the Hotel to the Airport",
    "translate_tipo": "One Way"
    ...
}
```

I tried with $filter without success, the result is the same:

```
  translate_tipo: {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$translate.locales.valor",
      "as": "string",
      "cond": {
        "$eq": [
          "$$string.clave",
          "EN"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

What am I missing?
I appreciate any suggestions that help me find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of investigation, I could see that unwind was the solution combined with a couple of match and a projection.

I used two lookup as a join, after I used a project to obtain only required items, later I used unwind for locales items and two match to obtain the locale and finally a project to obtain just the translate text.

Maybe there are other ways to do it, but this one works perfectly for me

```
db.tipo_traslados.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "locales",
      "localField": "tipo",
      "foreignField": "etiqueta",
      "as": "tipot"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "locales",
      "localField": "descripcion",
      "foreignField": "etiqueta",
      "as": "descripciont"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      tipo: 1,
      traslado: 1,
      descripcion: 1,
      clave: 1,
      tipot: "$tipot.locales",
      descripciont: "$descripciont.locales"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$tipot"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$tipot"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$descripciont"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$descripciont"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "tipot.clave": "US"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "descripciont.clave": "US"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      tipo: "$tipot.valor",
      traslado: 1,
      descripcion: "$descripciont.valor",
      clave: 1,
      
    }
  }
])
```

The final result was

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f74c774bd714d0e90b2612d"),
    "clave": "apto-hotel",
    "descripcion": "One Way Transfer from the Airport to the Hotel",
    "tipo": "One Way",
    "traslado": "apto-hotel"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f74c865bd714d0e90b2612e"),
    "clave": "hotel-apto",
    "descripcion": "One Way Transfer from the Hotel to the Airport",
    "tipo": "One Way",
    "traslado": "hotel-apto"
  }
]
```